# Delphi fails to open database

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Windows 32, Delphi XE5. Database from Component ACE: Absolute database.

Form Create Procedure worked ok upto few hours ago. Suddenly resulted in error:

```
Cannot open File"Error Code 3" Error message: Can not find the path specified. Error 30364.
```

I have read many discussion with the same or similar problem but none gave me a good hint to solve.
The Procedure code is:

```
Procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
 begin
   ABSDatabase1.DatabaseFilename:= ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'LibCat.ABS';
   ABSDatabase1.Open;
   // showmessage(ABSDatabase1.Databasefilename);
   ABSTable1.TableName:='Cat';
   ABSTable1.Open;   // gives error
   ABSTable1.Last;
   GetAppVersionStr;
   Form1.Caption:=Form1.Caption +': Books Catalogue, ver. ' + Versione;
 end;
```

The database file is in the same folder as the Project exe file. Any path of the option file point to the same folder.

I cannot imagine what modication I did to get this error.

On a step by step debugging the Database opens regularly, but the open Table gives the error.
On Object Inspector for Database the FileName is specified as .\LibCat.abs

Comment: Sorry for the editing

Comment: Error 3 mean "The system cannot find the path specified". Clearly something is wrong with the database filename.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
It was really a silly reason:
I examined carefully the .dfm file and I found that on "Object Inspector" providing data to ABSDatabase1 I have written the name and put at the end of the string a carriage return and a new line. Of course these characters where not visible on ID, only on .dfm file.
I do not know why this additional keys caused the error, but as I cleared them the Form was regularly generated and the program run perfectly.
Hope this can be useful to someone else.